# Cannot take CAR of 2 (Common Lisp)

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and I'm trying to get to where I can iterate through a list of varying depth with CAR/CDR recursion. I've seen similar questions, but none address the exact problem I'm running into or how to solve it. In this example, I'm trying to square every number in the list:

```
(defun square-list (x)
  (cond ((and (atom x) (not (equal x nil)))
         (cons (* x x) (or (square-list (car x)) (square-list (cdr x)))))
        (t (or (square-list (car x)) (square-list (cdr x))))))
```

From reading, I was under the impression that both the CAR and CDR of an atom would either be nil or another atom. What am I getting wrong here? Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
I've solved the basic problem of squaring a number in a list of arbitrary depth (e.g. '(1 ((2) 3) (4 5))), but I'm still getting an error when I throw a letter into the mix. Here's the new code:

```
(defun square-list (x)
          (cond ((null x) nil) 
                ((and (atom x) (numberp x)) (* x x))
                (t (cons (square-list (car x)) (square-list (cdr x))))))
```

The error is still the same: "Cannot take CAR of A" with list '(a ((2) 3) (4 5)).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to operate recursively on a list, then you should think about two things: the termination case, for instance what happens when the list is empty, and the recursive case, for instance what happens when the list has at least one element.

In your case, when the list is empty, no number must be squared, so return the empty list. Otherwise, you must build (i.e. `cons`) a new list, whose first element is the square of the first element of the list (i.e. `(car x)`) and the rest of the list is obtained by squaring the rest of the list (i.e. `(cdr x)`).

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

```
CL-USER>  (defun square-list (x)
            (if (null x)
                nil
                (cons (* (car x) (car x)) (square-list (cdr x)))))

SQUARE-LIST
CL-USER> (square-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

By the way, you can take the `car` and the `cdr` only of lists, not of atoms (this will cause a run-time error).

```
CL-USER> (car (list 1 2 3 4 5))
1
CL-USER> (cdr (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (car 1)
The value 1 is not of the expected type LIST.
[Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

If what you need, instead, is to square all the elements of a tree (i.e. a list containing arbitrarily nested sublist) you need to change the function to manage three different cases, and not two:

1. if the list is empty, returns the empty list,
2. if the first element of the list is itself a list, then apply recursively `square-list` to it and “cons” the result obtained with an application of `square-list` to the rest of the list,
3. otherwise, return a new list squaring the first element of the list (which now we know it is surely an atom) and “consing” the result with the result of squaring the rest of the list.

For instance:

```
CL-USER> (defun square-list (x)
           (cond ((null x) nil)
                 ((listp (car x)) (cons (square-list (car x))
                                        (square-list (cdr x))))
                 (t (cons (* (car x) (car x)) (square-list (cdr x))))))
SQUARE-LIST
CL-USER> (square-list '(1 ((2 3) (4))))
(1 ((4 9) (16)))
```

As last remarks, note that the above function are not tail recursive. A simple way to make tail recursive the first one is to use the classical “accumulator” strategy.

```
CL-USER> (defun square-list (x &optional accumulator)
           (if (null x)
               (reverse accumulator)
               (square-list (cdr x) (cons (* (car x) (car x)) accumulator))))
SQUARE-LIST
CL-USER> (square-list '(1 2 3 4 5))
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand tail-recursive functions well, but my goal is to produce a function that works on a list of arbitrary depth, e.g., (1 ((2) 3) (4)). I think this is called CAR/CDR recursion.

Comment: @stymies_camel, ok, I've changed the answer.